# Segmentation fault trying to execute a MinGW compiled C++ winapi test program

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw

I have trouble executing some winapi code. I don't know if the reason is because I missed something in the compilation process or if the test program is wrong; but when I execute the program the Bitmap defintion line is giving a **segfault**.

here is the test program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

int WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  Gdiplus::PixelFormat* pf = new Gdiplus::PixelFormat();
  Gdiplus::Bitmap* bitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(100, 100, *pf);
  return 0;
}
```

and here is the compilation instruction  :

```
> mingw32-g++ main.cpp -lgdiplus -o main.exe
```

When I execute, I have this throw :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00403da3 in Gdiplus::Image::Image (this=0x0, image=0x0, status=Gdiplus::Ok) at c:/mingw/include/gdiplus/gdiplusheaders.h:142
142                     nativeImage(image), lastStatus(status) {}
```

*I did some winapi tutorial and created a window before so I think my MinGW installation has nothing wrong.*

What could be the problem ?

Comment: I don't think `Gdiplus::PixelFormat* pf = new Gdiplus::PixelFormat();` is right.  `PixelFormat` is just an int, so what you wind up calling `Gdiplus::Bitmap` with 0. You're supposed to pass in one of the [defined pixel format constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534412(v=vs.85).aspx). Also, you don't have to `new` everything in C++. Usually it's better if you don't `new` at all.

Comment: GDI+ also needs explicit initialization. I don't know how to do this in C++.

Comment: Windows does not issue segmentation faults. What is your runtime environment?

Comment: Looks like a gdb run.

Comment: @IInspectable it's a `gdb` capture indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because GDI+ is not being initialized. You could simply call `Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup` at the top of `main` and `Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown` at the end, but by wrapping it in a class we get to take [advantage of RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and automate the initialization and release with less muss and fuss should anything go wrong.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// GDI+ wrapper class
class GdiplusRAII
{
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

public:

    GdiplusRAII()
    {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput input;
        Gdiplus::Status status = Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &input, NULL);
        if (status != Gdiplus::Ok)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Could not initialize GDI+");
        }
    }
    ~GdiplusRAII()
    {
        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    }

};

int WinMain(HINSTANCE ,
            HINSTANCE ,
            LPSTR ,
            int ) // not using the parameters so I left them out.
{
    GdiplusRAII raii; // initialize GDI+

    // no need to new a PixelFormat. It is just an int associated with a 
    // collection of defined constants. I'm going to pick one that sounds 
    // reasonable to minimize the potential for a nasty surprise and use it 
    // directly in the Gdiplus::Bitmap constructor call. 

    // Probably no need to new the bitmap. In fact you'll find that most of 
    // the time it is better to not new at all. 
    Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(100, 100, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
    return 0;
    // GDI+ will be shutdown when raii goes out of scope and its destructor runs.
}
```

[Documentation on PixelFormat.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534412(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Nitpick: GDI+, not GDI; they are two separate APIs that just share names. Also you might want to explain (or copy the explanation in your comment) about why you switched to `PixelFormat32bppARGB`, since that is still a difference between your answer and the question (and 0 is either `PixelFormatUndefined` or `PixelFormatDontCare`)...

Comment: Will correct. I picked 32bit RGB because I don't think OP knew what they were getting from the pointer. And I don't like surprises the kind of surprises you can get from don't care.

Comment: That's the reason why I'm saying you should say that in your answer too =P

Comment: I'd also delete {copy|move} {ctors|assingnment operators}.